# Overlaying Silverlight control on top of HTML

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, silverlight

I am using WebBrowser control in silverlight to show html page inside a Silverlight application. I have a drop down menu in the Silverlight application which Hides behind this HTML page. How can I make the HTML page to stay behind the Silverlight Controls.
Here is the Xaml

```
<Usercontrol>
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent" SizeChanged="LayoutRoot_SizeChanged">
        <WebBrowser x:Name="HtmlHost"  /> 
  </Grid>

</UserControl>
```

and

```
private void LayoutRoot_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.HtmlHost.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            LayoutRoot.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        }
```

Below screen shot shows the overlay. Help Please!!
[image]

Comment: Set the `z-index` of the rendered `HtmlHost`?

Comment: I have no control over the rendered Html.. btwn just saw this article stackoverflow.com/questions/9393261. Seems we can't do it

Comment: You don't apply the CSS by overriding the rendered HTML, you look at the output created by the `HtmlHost` and then apply a style to it via a CSS file.